# I was reading the book of theory of programming languages by Diana Phelps-Terasaki and got stuck at this question which has been asked by my professor

Tags: computer-science

what are the effects providing lazy evaluation in Imperative Languages? my answer was "It is a technique which is being used to postpone the evaluation of the expression until it’s components are needed, Basically why are you running a block of code when you don’t need to use it somewhere so lazy evaluation postpones all these type of expressions. It is also called call-by-need." and then I start explaining what actually imperative languages but the Prof. Said my boy you are wrong? please explain in detail what are the effects basically?

Comment: We can't read your prof's mind and it would help to have the exact question. I'm having a hard time parsing "what are the effects providing lazy evaluation". (effects of providing? effects providing?) Without the `of` it sounds a bit like "what features does an imperative lang need to have to be able to do lazy".

Answer (score 0):

Lazy evaluation is the postponing of an evaluation until the **result** of the evaluation is needed. So really it is: Why evaluate the expression if the result is not used.